# How to get the toolbar textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Need to get the entered textbox value in toolbar. And I want to save that value in Database. How can I print the entered textbox value in alert. I am using the following code textbox,

```
 <!--begin snippet: js hide: false -->

 <!--language: lang-js -->


 toolbar: { 
            cls: "pq-toolbar-search",
       items: [ 
                { type: '<span> Total Leave : </span>'},
                { type: 'textbox', cls:'holiday_year',listeners: 
                     [{ "click": function (evt, ui) {                   
                                   alert("value..."+$(this).val()); 
                                 }  
                     }]
                },
                { type: '<span> &nbsp&nbsp </span>'},
                { type: 'button',label:'Submit', cls:'saveData',listeners: 
                     [{ "click": function (evt, ui) {                 
                                    saveData();                 
                                 }
                     }]
                },
             ]
        }

      <!-- end snippet -->
```

Here I have written click function for textbox. I think its not correct I want to write the correct functionality to get the textbox value and pass in to one ajax call.

Please help me how can I get the value and pass into ajax.

Comment: For start, try doing a `console.log(evt, this)` on the textbox click event handler, and see what these two values hold.

Comment: yes it has hold. But once I enter any value, I want to click the textbox again. Then only it will get data. So instead of click function which one is correct?

Comment: Try [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) maybe?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net